# How to unit test file uploads with MockHttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've a Spring (3.0) Controller with a method which has `HttpServletRequest` as one of the parameters, since it's handling (multiple) file uploads.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/classified/{idClassified}/dealer/{idPerson}/upload",
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public final String uploadClassifiedPicture(
    @PathVariable int idClassified,
    @PathVariable int idPerson, 
    @RequestParam String token, 
    HttpServletRequest request);
```

How to Unit Test it? I know I can create a `MockHttpServletRequest`, but I don't know how to pass one or more files to it.

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("POST", 
     "/classified/38001/dealer/54/upload?token=dfak241adf");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend to change the method signature a bit, to make the uploaded file a normal parameter (of type [`MultipartFile`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) *(not [`CommonsMultipartFile`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html))*):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/classified/{idClassified}/dealer/{idPerson}/upload",
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public final String uploadClassifiedPicture(
    @PathVariable int idClassified,
    @PathVariable int idPerson, 
    @RequestParam String token, 
    @RequestParam MultipartFile content);
```

Then you can use a [`MockMultipartFile`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartFile.html) in your test:

```
final String fileName = "test.txt";
final byte[] content = "Hallo Word".getBytes();
MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile =
       new MockMultipartFile("content", fileName, "text/plain", content);

uploadClassifiedPicture(1, 1, "token", mockMultipartFile);
```

---

If you do not want to change the method signature, then you can use [`MockMultipartHttpServletRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartHttpServletRequest.html) instead.

It has a method [`addFile(MultipartFile file)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartHttpServletRequest.html#addFile%28org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile%29). And of course the required parameter can be a `MockMultipartFile`.

Comment: `MultipartFile` looks really interesting, because it narrows down the usage to file upload and the interface looks much clearer. However, I'm afraid I can't use it, because it supports only one file at a time and not multiple files upload (with the number of files to upload being open, in my case from 1 to 7).

Comment: @stivlo: what about an Array of MultipartFile: `MultipartFile[]`?

Comment: I just realize that I forgot to answer this, but the array trick worked perfectly, thank you Ralf

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the MockMvc object as well as MockMvcRequestBuilders to send a test file upload request to your controller:

```
@Test
public void testSendNotEmptyFile() throws Exception {

          mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("Your controller URL")
            .file("file", "Test Content".getBytes())
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```